# How can I change scene by just clicking a sprite(Button) on AndEngine?

Tags: android, andengine, scene

I am trying to make button that can change scene.
public class StartBtn extends Sprite {

```
boolean position = false;

public StartBtn(float pX, float pY, ITextureRegion pTextureRegion,
        VertexBufferObjectManager pVertexBufferObjectManager) {
    super(pX, pY, pTextureRegion, pVertexBufferObjectManager);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


@Override
public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float localAreaX, float localAreaY) {
    if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()) {
        MainActivity.StartGame();

    }
    return true;
}
```

}

and StartGame() at MainActivity is like this

`public void StartGame() {
    this.mEngine.setScene(new MainGameScene(this));
}`

But it has error on static, and I can't think of other ways. Is there any examples that I can help?

Comment: onAreaTouched is defined into StartBtn class?

Comment: @N_Turtle, I advice you to follow http://www.matim-dev.com/full-game-tutorial---part-1.html blog and it will be much much easier for you to switch between scenes and manage all your scenes and resources